# display local pdf file using UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentinteraction

I want to display a local pdf file using `UIDocumentInteractionController`
Here is my code :

```
pole = Pole.getWithMinor(minorBeacon)
    var address = pole.pdf

    if  pole != nil {
        var urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(pole.pdf, ofType: "pdf")
        let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: urlpath!)
        //pdfView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        println(url)
        let docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL : url)
        docController.UTI = "com.adobe.pdf"
        docController.delegate = self
        docController.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
```

the error is :

```
2015-06-02 15:57:08.390 LePetitPoucet[4232:2026014] *** Assertion failure in -[UIDocumentInteractionController setURL:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.93/UIDocumentInteractionController.m:1024
2015-06-02 15:57:08.391 LePetitPoucet[4232:2026014] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme (null).  Only the file scheme is supported.'
```

when i create a webWiew, the PDF is displayed well but i want to use pdf native viewer instead. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one always gets me too

`let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: urlpath!)` is wrong

you want

`let url : NSURL! = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlpath!)`